# Why doesn't Django template language allow something like a[ 0 ][ 1 ]?

Tags: python, django

When I was trying to access a tuple inside a list in the Django template format, I found out I couldn't access it with `a[ 0 ][ 1 ]`, instead I had to use `a.0.1`.

Suppose that `a` is something like

```
a = [
    ( 'a', 'apple' ),
    ( 'b', 'bee'   ),
]
```

Why doesn't Django template language support `a[ 0 ][ 1 ]`? In normal Python programming, `a.0.1` would give you a syntax error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Django docs on [the template API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#render) explain this nicely:

> Dots have a special meaning in template rendering. A dot in a variable name signifies a lookup. Specifically, when the template system encounters a dot in a variable name, it tries the following lookups, in this order:
>
> - Dictionary lookup. Example: `foo["bar"]`
> - Attribute lookup. Example: `foo.bar`
> - List-index lookup. Example: `foo[bar]`
>
> The template system uses the first lookup type that works. It's short-circuit logic. Here are a few examples:
>
> ```
> >>> from django.template import Context, Template
> >>> t = Template("My name is {{ person.first_name }}.")
> >>> d = {"person": {"first_name": "Joe", "last_name": "Johnson"}}
> >>> t.render(Context(d))
> "My name is Joe."
>
> >>> class PersonClass: pass
> >>> p = PersonClass()
> >>> p.first_name = "Ron"
> >>> p.last_name = "Nasty"
> >>> t.render(Context({"person": p}))
> "My name is Ron."
>
> >>> t = Template("The first stooge in the list is {{ stooges.0 }}.")
> >>> c = Context({"stooges": ["Larry", "Curly", "Moe"]})
> >>> t.render(c)
> "The first stooge in the list is Larry."
> ```

[Variable._resolve_lookup in django.templates.base](https://github.com/django/django/blob/e60ad2b18ec8ef2d43f3653af8c9ba2477263ba7/django/template/base.py#L738-783) appears to be the function responsible for this, and hasn't changed much [since the oldest revision I can find](https://github.com/django/django/blob/33db6db21c39a4b5ed0cd3f4629e7391e36a94a7/django/core/template.py#L354-397)

Answer (score 3):

You can find some information about this in the [django book](http://djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter04/):

> The beginning of the chapter should explain why it works this way:
>   In the previous chapter, you may have noticed something peculiar in how we returned the text in our example views. Namely, the HTML was hard-coded directly in our Python code, like this:

```
def current_datetime(request):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    html = "<html><body>It is now %s.</body></html>" % now
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

> Although this technique was convenient for the purpose of explaining how views work, it’s not a good idea to hard-code HTML directly in your views. Here’s why:
>
> - Any change to the design of the page requires a change to the Python code. The design of a site tends to change far more frequently than the underlying Python code, so it would be convenient if the design could change without needing to modify the Python code.
> - Writing Python code and designing HTML are two different disciplines, and most professional Web development environments split these responsibilities between separate people (or even separate departments). Designers and HTML/CSS coders shouldn’t be required to edit Python code to get their job done.
> - It’s most efficient if programmers can work on Python code and designers can work on templates at the same time, rather than one person waiting for the other to finish editing a single file that contains both Python and HTML.
>
> For these reasons, it’s much cleaner and more maintainable to separate the design of the page from the Python code itself. We can do this with Django’s template system, which we discuss in this chapter.
>
> ...
>
> Dot lookups can be summarized like this: when the template system encounters a dot in a variable name, it tries the following lookups, in this order:
>
> - Dictionary lookup (e.g., foo["bar"])
> - Attribute lookup (e.g., foo.bar) 1
> - Method call (e.g., foo.bar())
> - List-index lookup (e.g., foo[2])
>
> The system uses the first lookup type that works. It’s short-circuit logic.

Answer (score 2):

The reason I would say that the django template language doesnt do XYZ way of accessing context data is because generally at that point you are doing too much in the template side vs your view that renders it.

The design decision of their template engine seems lighter than maybe some others which give you more pythonic direct access to data. But ideally you would be formatting th context before passing it in.

You also have the ability to create your own template filters for doing more custom processing of data.

Specific to your question, accesing child members using dot notation is the django template way to try multiple approaches to resolving the member. It tries dictionary keys, attributes, etc. in a certain order. You just use dot notation for everything.

Comment: "You are doing too much in the template side vs your view that renders it." That sums it up perfectly. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I liked your explanation and dbr's example. And I'm more of an example person lol. I still appreciate your answer!